# Cylindrical Decomposition vs Morse decomposition

Tags: differential-topology, computational-geometry, morse-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a polynomial Morse function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the ideal $I(\nabla f)$ generated by the partial derivatives $\partial_i f$, and assume that the real zero-set of this ideal is discrete.

Now, there are two decompositions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that I can write down:

1. the Morse decomposition given by the intersections of the descending/ascending manifolds, and
2. a Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition (CAD) with respect to the system of real polynomial equations $\{\partial_i f=0\}_i$.

What, if anything, is the relation between these two decompositions?

For example, in one dimension, a CAD must refine the Morse decomposition (I believe), because the Morse decomposition in this case partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into the maximal regions on which $f'$ is positive or negative, and the sign of $f'$ is constant on each cell of the CAD.
Could it be the case that, in higher dimensions, a CAD does not refine the Morse decomposition?

**Bonus:** what about the Morse-Bott case where the zero set $Z(I(\nabla f))$ has positive dimension?